# XCode: Why do my core data changes appear only after restarting the emulator?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data

### EDIT: I fixed it by removing the beginupdates() method

I'm new to iOS app development and I'm creating an iOS application in Swift using XCode. The app is a book lists app, where users can add the name, description, author of a book, and this book will appear as a table row in the home page of the app.

However, I'm facing a problem. Whenever I add a book and click save, the book added is not shown in the home page of the app. But when I restart my application/emulator, the book appears on the home page in the table row.

Here are some images of what's happening:
[image: home page]

[image: app restarted, book appears on home page]

Book appears when app is restarted.
[image: app restarted]
Here is some code:

AddBookViewController.swift
This UI View Controller class allows one to enter information into the text input fields and when done, they click save to save the book and are taken back to the home screen.

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

protocol AddBookProtocol {
    func addBook(book: Book) -> Bool
}
class AddBookViewController: UIViewController {
    private var BooksList: [Book] = []
    private var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext
    var addBookDelegate: AddBookProtocol?

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
        managedObjectContext = (appDelegate?.persistentContainer.viewContext)!
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var authorField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var genreField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var editionField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var isbnField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var dateField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var publisherField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var descriptionField: UITextField!

    @IBAction func saveButton() {

        let bookAdd = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Book", into: managedObjectContext)
            as! Book
        bookAdd.name = nameField.text
        bookAdd.author = authorField.text
        BooksList.append(bookAdd)
        let book = BooksList[BooksList.count - 1]

        let bookAdded = addBookDelegate?.addBook(book: book)
        if bookAdded != nil {
            // If there is a delegate, respond to whether it added book.
            if bookAdded == true {
                navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
            }
            else {
            }
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


    }
        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

CurrentBooksTableViewController.swift
This class displays all the books added/saved by the user. However, when you try to add a book in the add book screen and click save, the book appears only when the application is restarted.

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class CurrentBooksTableViewController: UITableViewController, AddBookProtocol {

    var BooksList: [Book] = []
    private var currentLib: Library?
    private var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext

    let SECTION_BOOKS = 0
    let SECTION_COUNT = 1

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
        managedObjectContext = (appDelegate?.persistentContainer.viewContext)!
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Library")
        do {
            let librarys = try managedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [Library]
            if librarys.count == 0 {
                currentLib = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Library", into: managedObjectContext)
                    as? Library
                saveData()
            }
            else {
                currentLib = librarys.first
                BooksList = currentLib?.books?.allObjects as! [Book]
            }
        }
        catch {
            fatalError("Failed to fetch books: \(error)")
        }

    }
    func saveData() {
        do {
            try managedObjectContext.save()
        }
        catch let error {
            print("Could not save Core Data: \(error)")
        }
    }
    @IBAction func unwindSegue(_ sender: UIStoryboardSegue){

    }

    func addBook(book: Book) -> Bool  {

        currentLib?.addToBooks(book)
        saveData()

        BooksList.append(book)
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: BooksList.count - 1, section: 0)], with: .automatic)

        tableView.reloadSections([SECTION_COUNT], with: .automatic)
         return true
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle
    {
        if indexPath.section == SECTION_BOOKS {
            return .delete
        }
        return .none
    }

    // Override to support editing the table view.
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt
        indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            // Delete the row from the data source
            let deletedBook = BooksList.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            currentLib?.removeFromBooks(deletedBook)

            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)

            tableView.reloadSections([SECTION_COUNT], with: .automatic)
            saveData()
        }
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 2

    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        if (section == SECTION_COUNT)
        {
            return 1
        }
        return BooksList.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cellResuseIdentifier = "BookCell"
        if indexPath.section == SECTION_COUNT {
            cellResuseIdentifier = "TotalCell"
        }
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellResuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)

        // Configure the cell...
        if indexPath.section == SECTION_BOOKS {
            let bookCell = cell as! BookTableViewCell

            bookCell.nameLabel.text = BooksList[indexPath.row].name
            bookCell.authorLabel.text = BooksList[indexPath.row].author
        }
        else {
            cell.textLabel?.text = "\(BooksList.count) Books"
        }

        return cell

    }

    // Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let controller = segue.destination as? AddBookViewController {
            controller.addBookDelegate = self
        }
    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong?
Your help would be much appreciated.
Kind regards

Comment: Your fetch request is only fetched during viewDidLoad and your view is only loaded once. Look at [NSFetchedResultsViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/nsfetchedresultscontroller.html) which helps to monitor for any changes and notify you so that you can update your tableview

Answer (score 0):

You have to call save method on NSManagedObjectContext, probably this method is called in AppDelegate when app is terminated.

similar to this what you have already in CurrentBooksTableViewController.saveData()